# "elapsed" or "passed"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I want to express the fact, that a specific time has passed.
However, I need to refer to a **point in time**, rather than to a **time span**. Can I use

```
The expected time of arrival has already passed.
```

or

```
The expected time of arrival has already elapsed.
```

Are there other ways to better express this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer **passed** for a point in time, as in your example.

People also say **the time has gone** but **passed** is better here.

**Elapsed** or **passed** are possible for a period of time.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elapse